# How can I fix the issue of my road object being smaller than expected in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Creating and stretching an object is not working properly.

I am trying to create a road system for a 2D top-down project in Unity. The process is simple:

1. User clicks on the screen, preview line appears
2. Preview lines follows the mouse cursor
3. After the second click endpoint is set and line transforms into a gameobject with the same size and position as a line.

Everything works until transformation, basically code creates the object, but it's much smaller than expected. Here are some screenshots:

[Preview line works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o63k4.png)
[Object created after second click (preview line on previous screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQNWO.png)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RoadBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject roadPrefab; // Prefab to instantiate the road
    public LineRenderer previewLine; // LineRenderer to show the temporary road preview

    private Vector2 startingPoint; // Starting point of the road
    private Vector2 endingPoint; // Ending point point of the road
    private bool isBuildingRoad; // Flag to indicate if the user is currently building a road

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (!isBuildingRoad)
            {
                // Start building road
                isBuildingRoad = true;
                startingPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                previewLine.positionCount = 2;
                previewLine.SetPosition(0, startingPoint);
                previewLine.SetPosition(1, startingPoint);
            }
            else
            {
                // Finish building road
                endingPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                CreateRoad(startingPoint, endingPoint);
                isBuildingRoad = false;
                previewLine.positionCount = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (isBuildingRoad)
        {
            // Update road preview
            Vector2 currentPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            previewLine.SetPosition(1, currentPoint);
        }
    }

private void CreateRoad(Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
{
    // Calculate road position
    Vector2 roadPosition = start;

    // Calculate road size and rotation
    float roadSize = Vector2.Distance(start, end);
    float roadRotation = Mathf.Atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    // Instantiate the road game object
    GameObject road = Instantiate(roadPrefab, roadPosition, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, roadRotation));
    road.transform.localScale = new Vector3(roadSize, 1f, 1f);
}



}
```

Comment: What is the size of this road model?

Comment: It's a square 32x32 pixels

Comment: A sprite? what's its pixels per unit?

Comment: Yeah, I just created a plain square 32x32 and coloured it in Photoshop, then exported as .jpg and imported into the Unity, then created an 2D sprite and made a prefab out of it. 

Its 100 pixels per unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the same effect, you need to do two more things in the sprite import settings

1. Change **Pixels Per Unit** to 32, so that the edge length of the sprite becomes 1 in the world.
2. Open the **Sprite Editor**, change **Custom Pivot** to `X:0 Y:0.5` (the middle-left of the sprite)

Comment: @PaulSotena remember to vote it up as helpful too.

Comment: Yeah... I don't have reputation yet.